# How to set my screen boundaries on a turtle drawing

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I have a set code here that I use to generate a unique image each time the code is run; how do I set it to only draw within the boundaries of my tkinter screen?

Here is the code:

```
import random
import turtle
maker=turtle.Turtle()
maker.getscreen().delay(0)
maker.getscreen().tracer(0)
n=random.randint(1,360)
m=random.randint(0,100)
r=random.randint(0,50)
d=random.randint(1,2)
maker2=maker.clone()
maker3=maker.clone()
maker4=maker.clone()
maker.goto(0,0)
maker2.goto(0,0)
maker3.goto(0,0)
maker4.goto(0,0)
#top right
maker.goto(50, 50)
#bottom right
maker2.goto(50, -50)
#bottom left
maker3.goto(-50, -50)
#top left
maker4.goto(-50, 50)
while r<50:
    for i in range (0,m):
        maker.forward(m)
        maker2.forward(m)
        maker3.backward(m)
        maker4.backward(m)
        for i in range (0,r):
            if d == 1: 
                maker.right(n)
                maker2.right(n*-1)
                maker3.left(n*-1)
                maker4.left(n)
            elif d == 2:
                maker.left(n)
                maker2.left(n*-1)
                maker3.right(n*-1)
                maker4.right(n)
        maker.forward(m)
        maker2.forward(m)
        maker3.backward(m)
        maker4.backward(m)
    n=n+1
    r = r + 1
    n=random.randint(0,359)
maker.goto(0,0)
maker2.goto(0,0)
maker3.goto(0,0)
maker4.goto(0,0)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: you could get current position and "add" value which you will use in `forward` (using also `angle` and `sin()`, `cos()`) to get destination position before you move. and then you can check if destination will be in bondaries. If not then skip move or use smaller value in `forward`.

Comment: If you notice, the code itself isn't drawing the same thing over and over, as It randomly will set its own direction and forward values, there is no way for me to set a shorter 'forward' and actually still keep it in screen, as it may choose to just go forward multiple times the same number. The directional values will not make it turn; etc. also I want the window set as a tkinter screen value, not a set number of pixels, so on different computers, this could vary. I want for it to know, that if it is hitting the edge of the canvas, it needs to hit another value and turn some other way. How?

Comment: it doesn't matter how randomly is move - you can get `m` before you use it in `forward()` and calculate `dx = m*sin(angel)` `dy = m*cos(angle)` and add to current position `x,y = pos() ; x += dx ; y += dy` to get destination position. You can also always get canvas size (`canvas['width']`, `canvas['height']`) and check if `x,y` will be still in canvas.

Comment: thank you; the checking the canvas, and running the whole loop in another if statement might work.

Comment: actually, i should probably just add it to my WHILE statement.

Comment: I would do function because you have to check it before every `forward()` and `backward()`

Comment: differnt idea: first calculate all points/lines (without drawing), then rescale all points to fit to canvas, and finally draw it.

Comment: BTW, the `for i in range (0,r):` loop is rather inefficient. Instead of looping, compute the total angle. Eg, `rn = r * n` ... `maker.right(rn)`.

Comment: A simple way to keep the drawing (mostly) in the visible portion of the canvas is to create a function that tests each turtle after you move it, and if it's too far from the centre, move it towards the centre. Eg, if the turtle is `t` you can do `x, y = t.position()` `if abs(x) > width or abs(y) > height: t.goto(x / 2, y / 2)`. However, this will make many of the drawings _very_ dense, so you'll need to reduce the ranges of some of your parameters.

Comment: these are great ideas all; thanks

Comment: oh and also @PM2Ring I dont know how to do that. computing the total angle? the i in range is a loop that i understand.

Comment: `for i in range (0,r): maker.right(n)` performs the same rotation as `rn = r * n; maker.right(rn)`, except the 2nd version is much more efficient, especially when `r` is large. Also `maker2.right(n*-1)` should be written as `maker2.right(-n)`, or in the no-loop version `maker2.right(-rn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not showing the drawing until it's complete, one simple fix is to make a move, check if the move takes you out of the canvas, and then if it does, simply undo that move:

```
from random import randint, choice
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

width, height = screen.window_width() - 30, screen.window_height() - 30  # -30 to account for window borders, etc.

maker1 = Turtle(visible=False)
maker2 = maker1.clone()
maker3 = maker1.clone()
maker4 = maker1.clone()

maker1.goto(50, 50)  # top right
maker2.goto(50, -50)  # bottom right
maker3.goto(-50, -50)  # bottom left
maker4.goto(-50, 50)  # top left

n = randint(1, 360)
m = randint(0, 100)
r = randint(0, 50)
d = choice([True, False])

def out_of_bounds(turtle):
    return not (-width//2 < turtle.xcor() < width//2 and -height//2 < turtle.ycor() < height//2)

while r < 50:
    for i in range(0, m):

        maker1.forward(m)
        maker2.forward(m)
        maker3.backward(m)
        maker4.backward(m)

        if any(out_of_bounds(turtle) for turtle in screen.turtles()):
            for turtle in screen.turtles():
                turtle.undo()

        if d:
            maker1.right(r * n)
            maker2.right(-r * n)
            maker3.left(-r * n)
            maker4.left(r * n)
        else:
            maker1.left(r * n)
            maker2.left(-r * n)
            maker3.right(-r * n)
            maker4.right(r * n)

        maker1.forward(m)
        maker2.forward(m)
        maker3.backward(m)
        maker4.backward(m)

        if any(out_of_bounds(turtle) for turtle in screen.turtles()):
            for turtle in screen.turtles():
                turtle.undo()

    r += 1
    n = randint(0, 359)

screen.update()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

I agree with @PM2Ring about adjusting image density (above is *not* an example but you'll see one soon enough).

Comment: i know i just marked this solved with that code you just posted but unfortunately, i need to go ahead and unsolve it. i ran some testing with that code and it is actually not working correctly. some how, in some instances it has changed the code so that it is no longer doing the exact same image on each run for each of the four corners of the canvas, which was the goal, so that it would make a continuous pattern. I can see that yours appears symmetrical but two of four of my tests have not. image coming.

Comment: I cant get the picture to upload for some reason.

Comment: @fantascey, I believe I've modified my code to correct this issue -- give it another try.  I'm really enjoying the images created by the constrained code.

Comment: yeah took me awhile to get it but i was really playing with what all i could do and how to make the computer make its own arts.

Comment: this does look sufficiently corrected. I had no errors with the four corners in 3 test runs. so far as the lines however, i did have one that set an extremely high number of loops and i wondered about it. So far as the images, I did play around with trying to save the outputs as .png files at one point but there was a module that i needed that wasnt operating correctly. I would love to save them, but as I write the .png files it overwrites them unless i can also save every new one under another numerical index maybe. not sure. anyways, thank you for this.

Comment: seems like a simple code when its done; but when i was trying to create it (some months ago actually) then no one had tried to do such a thing with turtle graphics so it was kind of an unexplored concept to try and get it to do its own thing. I have several saved test runs where it just scribbles haha

Comment: So I have concluded that the final fix was a good one but still needed some adjusting for personal satisfactory in the program. when i ran the testing for the final code, it was so dense in some shapes that it can be like a large blackened scribble. We can adjust the variables for 'r' and 'm' so that the randomly chosen integers, rather than 50 and 100 are 20 and 20 or 30 and 15, This gives enough room for good shapes and not so much density that you get a blob. Clearer images that way but also, if integers are say, 5 or less, than you might just get an x. but i like that.